# Draw a slash line over glyphicon or font-awesome icon using CSS

Tags: css, font-awesome, glyphicons

I would like to draw a slash line over a glyph icon or an icon from font-awesome.
For example, I want to put slash over this icon as "no wifi available.

```
<i class="fa fa-signal"></i>
```

I tried to do it with stacking but for that I would need an one icon that is a slash.

```
<div class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-signal fa-stack-1x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-ban fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>                
</div>
Wi-Fi
```

Is there an easier way to have a slash over the signal icon?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Font awesome uses the :before tag for icons, why not use the :after pseudo and `.fa.fa-signal:after {content: "/"; color: red;}` and position it with css.

```css
.fa.fa-signal:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "/";
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  left: 7px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-signal fa-2x"></i>
```

Comment: Please, can you give an example.

Comment: @feradz I've added an example to my answer, could you click the tick next to the answer if this is correct.

Comment: Works well thanks. additional note: don't forget to set the parent element with 'position: relative'

Answer (score 24):

I suggest to use `.fa-ban` icon that will cover the wi-fi icon.
Please see an example.

```css
#container {
  position: relative
}

#nested {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  font-size: 200%;
  color: rgba(217, 83, 79, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h4>
  <i class="fa fa-rss" id="container">
    <i class="fa fa-ban" id="nested"></i>
  </i>
</h4>
```

Comment: .fa-ban covers too much. Some icons will be illegible when covered by it.

Answer (score 12):

Now this is supported natively by Font Awesome. The feature is called "stacked icons". See [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons).

Code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-signal fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-ban fa-stack-2x" style="color:Tomato"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: .fa-ban covers WAY too much; most icons will be illegible when covered by it

Answer (score 10):

Another approach, which I believe ends up with a better visual is use a rotated rectangle:

```css
.fa.fa-signal:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;
    height: 141.421356%;
    top: -20.710678%;
    display: block;
    background: red;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-signal fa-2x"></i>
```

Explaining some number which might look magic:

- `width: 141.421356%` - calculates the diagonal of the parent square (parent_square_size * square_root(2))
- `top: -20.710678%` - moves red line a bit above the top to get it right positioned when rotated, this is half of the exceeding width
- `left: 50%` and `translate(-50%, 0)` - to center align it

Answer (score 10):

Adding yet another method to achieve this effect, I like using the pipe (|) with FontAwesome stacking and rotation because the style rules are simple.

Tip: you could use a different font for the pipe to get rounded ends etc. You can also achieve the same effect without a wrapping tag but you'd have to add your own stacking/positioning rules.

[Screenshot of crossed-out icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx9mO.png)

```css
.crossed-out:after{
        content: '|';
        color: red;
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<span class="fa-stack crossed-out">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-stack-1x fa-signal"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using font-awesome slash icon  (FA Version 5.4.0+)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-signal fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-slash fa-stack-1x" style="text-shadow: 0.1em 0.15em white;"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Makes sense to use the method advocated by font awesome.  More information on this approach can be found on the font awesome site - https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/  ( this is for an older version but the approach is still the same )

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternative is use "clip-path: polygon" for ":after" absolute object and play with left,top,width,height attributes.
Also bar size  is consistent to icon dimension.

```css
.notavailable {
   position: relative;
}

.notavailable:after {
   content: " ";
   position: absolute;
   left: 8%;
   top: -6%;
   width: 88%;
   height: 110%;
   clip-path: polygon(0 0, 12% 0, 100% 100%, 88% 100%);
   background-color: rgba(150, 2, 2, 0.9);
}

i{ margin:15px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-signal fa-1x notavailable"></i>
<i class="fa fa-signal fa-2x notavailable"></i>
<i class="fa fa-signal fa-4x notavailable"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to the fa-ban example above. This uses fractional em positioning instead of pixels. This way the positioning works no matter what the current font size is. This also uses a class instead of an id so that it can be used multiple times on the same page. I also changed the slash to be full red. A tool-tip popup was also added using the title tag.

```
.kc-fa-container { position:relative; }
.kc-fa-nested    { position: absolute;
left: -0.125em;
top: -0.125em;
font-size: 1.5em;
color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
<i class="fa fa-rss kc-fa-contianer" title="No WiFi">
  <i class="fa fa-ban kc-fa-nested"></i>
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update FontAwesome: `v5.7.0`**

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwhumkyb/)